# Cantor space is Polish

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that the Cantor space $2^\omega$ is a Polish space (i.e. a separable, completely metrizable space.)

Indeed, since $2^\omega$ is second-countable and compact Hausdorff, it is metrizable; and since every second-countable space is separable, $2^\omega$ is also separable. I do not see, however, why is $2^\omega$ **completely metrizable**. Where does this come from?

Comment: What can you cay about a compact metric space?

Comment: Even ignoring Sangchul's observation, have you checked whether the standard metric on $2^\omega$ is complete?

Answer (score 2):

Any compact metric space is complete (in any compatible metric). This is a standard fact.